# Build dependency: OpenWrt can only be built on a case-sensitive filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, case-sensitive, openwrt

I'm trying to execute operation "make menuconfig" for an OpenWRT project.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 which is made for Windows 10.

I get this error(in Ubuntu):

```
root@DESKTOP-OF2R9RL:/mnt/c/Users/TITAS/work/openwrt# make menuconfig
Checking 'working-make'... ok.
Checking 'case-sensitive-fs'... failed.
...
Checking 'ldconfig-stub'... ok.

Build dependency: OpenWrt can only be built on a case-sensitive filesystem

/mnt/c/Users/TITAS/work/openwrt/include/prereq.mk:9: recipe for target 'prereq' failed
Prerequisite check failed. Use FORCE=1 to override.
/mnt/c/Users/TITAS/work/openwrt/include/toplevel.mk:179: recipe for target 'staging_dir/host/.prereq-build' failed
make: *** [staging_dir/host/.prereq-build] Error 1
```

I tried to change case-sensitivity of the folder "openwrt"(in Windows CMD):

```
C:\Windows\system32>fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo C:\Users\TITAS\work\openwrt enable
Case sensitive attribute on directory C:\Users\TITAS\work\openwrt is enabled.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

but the same problem persists.

What should I do?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't think this question is related to git?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm fairly new to OverStackFlow. I'll try to change my question